# how to get channel and group members using teams js

Tags: microsoft-teams-js

Is it possible to retrieve channel and chat members using the Teams JavaScript SDK without resorting to the Graph API? Equivalents in the Graph API include:

- GET /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/members
- GET /chats/{chat-id}/members
- GET /users/{user-id | user-principal-name}/chats/{chat-id}/members